# Enviar lista postman

Tags: postman

Buenas noches amigos quisiera saber si alguien me puede indicar cómo enviar una lista de objetos por Postman.
Gracias por su colaboración

Comment: Envias un array json

Comment: Requiere autenticación? Tenés un ejemplo de lo que querés mandar?

Comment: No requiere autenticación, es sólo algo básico, gracias

Comment: Qué tiene que ver vb.net en la pregunta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Documentación que te puede ayudar. https://community.postman.com/t/sending-an-array-as-form-data/4606

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Answer (score 0):

Si normalmente ponemos nombre de la variable entre comillas simples(""), dos puntos (:) y valor también entre comillas simples "" para una variable:

```
  "centro":"CENTRO".
```

Y para un objeto utilizamos llaves {} y las variables separadas por coma (,).

```
"datos":{
                    "centro":"CENTRO",
                    "director":"DIRECTOR"
                  }
```

Para una lista utilizamos corchetes ([]): Para una lista que se llame listBloc, que esta dentro del objecto datos, y cada miembro de listBloc tuviera: id, fechaCreacion y usuarioCreacion.

```
"datos":{                    
          "centro":"CENTRO",
          "director":"DIRECTOR",
          "listBloc":[{
                                 "id":"1",
                                 "fechaCreacion":"1554975590262",
                                 "usuarioCreacion":"xxxxxx"
                                            
                      }, 
                      {
                                 "id":"2",
                                 "fechaCreacion":"1554975990262",
                                 "usuarioCreacion":"xxxxx2"     
                      }]
}
```